# python importing modules error for dependencies

Tags: python, importerror

I'm trying to understand the whole Python importing / modules / package business, but I'm stuck on this particular issue.

My directory structure:

```
.
├── README.md
├── mypackage
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── red.py
│   ├── blue.py
│   ├── green.py
│   └── tests
│       └── red_tests.py
│       └── green_tests.py
└── go.py
```

and my importing code looks like this:

```
# __init__.py
from red import Red 
from green import Green 

# blue.py
from red import Red

# green.py
from red import Red
from blue import Blue

# go.py
from mypackage import Red, Green
```

but running `go.py` gives this error when trying to access a static class variable of the `Green` class:

```
NameError: global name 'Green' is not defined
```

How can I fix this?

---

### EDIT

Apologies - it turned out to be a circular dependency problem. I apologize for the confusion!

Comment: where is `donkey.py`?

Comment: sorry changed names, now edited

Comment: Where is `Green` defined? In `green.py` you only import Red and Blue. What is the content of `red.py`?

Comment: It works fine in my computer, with python 2.7.3.

Answer (score 1):

try create a file `__init__.py` in the same directory with `go.py`

Answer (score 1):

Python imports modules with relation to your current `PATH`, you can find out what it is this way:

```
import os
print os.environ['PYTHONPATH'].split(os.pathsep)
```

Now when importing stuff in any of your `.py` files, write the `import` location with the relation to your `PATH`.

So if say your `PATH` was `project/` (where the "project" directory is the root directory of your provided file structure), then `green.py` would be accessible using this syntax:

```
import mypackage.green
```

Comment: which is the same as `from mypackage import Green`, which I have done